# how to drag and drop in android?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, scroll

my android version is 2.2

I want to make ui like easyband ([youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92CS5k7jC-I))

so, how to drag and drop imageView or button between other layout?

and I want know insert imageView or button array of items to use drag and drop

plz help me

Answer (score 0):

Your answer would be [Android drag and drop framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html).

However, I guess you are just at the beginning to solve your problem, try to ask more **specific questions** (like I have tried **this method** and it's giving me **this error**) instead of looking for a **whole answer**

Comment: thanks your comment , actually my home language is not english. so i can't write detail. i still try to solve this problem.

Comment: The link you provided won't work. Ku_ says that he is writing for android 2.2 but the Drag and Drop functionality and link you provided is for Android 3.0 and up.

Comment: The link is working and he can start his research with that link.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean the link itself doesn't work, I meant that Drag and Drop won't work on Android 2.2. Also, the framework is in Android 3.0 and up. If he creates the application, it will not function because Android 2.2 does not have the library integrated in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a GridView that allows you to drop views from one area to another. Here is Bill Lahti's code and examples of the similar Drag and Drop effect on lower API's.

http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/moving-views-part-3/

http://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/03/03/improved-drag-drop-for-gridview/

Also, explore his content and hopefully you will find what you need.